# How to find out all the "hidden" official Rails guides?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For instance, I found [AJAX on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) via Google, but it is not listed on the [Rails Guides index page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not listed on the Rails Guides because most of the helper functions  like `link_to_remote` are not in Rails 3.

Comment: Are those functions deprecated?

Comment: Yeah, I believe they are. `link_to_remote` is available only till Rails 2.3.6. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote